# Routes not working properly in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

I am working with Codeigniter 4, Right now i want to execute simple function but i am getting following error

```
404 page not found
```

Here is my routes.php

```
$routes->post('login', 'Form::login');
```

Here is my "Form Controller",Where i am wrong ?

```
public function login()
   {
     echo "Hello world";
   }
```

In browser i type following url

```
localhost:8080/login
```

Comment: Do you Define the route like this  `$route['login'] = login';`?

Comment: And you call route as get and it's defined like a post.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama what is the solution then ? kindly post your answer so i can check at my side\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your route `post to get`.

```
$routes->get('login', 'Form::login');
```

The post route is for submitting your form data, While the get route is for getting your form data and showing your view file.